# Why My second view cannot jump back to the root view properly

Tags: swift, swiftui

My App currently has two pages, first page has a **circle plus** button which could lead us to a second page. Basically, I have a save button which after clicking it, we could get back to the rood page. I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/swiftui-how-to-pop-to-root-view) for **going back to root view**. I tried the most up voted code, his code works perfectly. I reduced his code to two scene (basically the same scenario as mine), which also works perfectly. But then I don't know why my own code, pasted below, doesn't work. Basically my way of handling going back to root view is the same as the one in the link.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  refridgerator_app
//
//  Created by Mingtao Sun on 12/22/20.
//

import SwiftUI
import UIKit
#if canImport(UIKit)
extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

#endif
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var fridge : Fridge
    private var dbStartWith=0;
    @State var pushed: Bool = false
    @State private var selection = 1;
    @State private var addFood = false;
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationView {
                List(fridge.container!){
                    food in NavigationLink(destination: FoodView()) {
                        Text("HI")
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Fridge Items"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                        NavigationLink(destination: AddFoodView(pushed: self.$pushed),isActive: self.$pushed) {
                                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle").resizable().frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                                        }.isDetailLink(false) )
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("Home")
            }
            .tag(1)
            
            
            Text("random tab")
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "bookmark.circle.fill")
                    Text("profile")
                }
                .tag(0)
        }.environmentObject(fridge)
        
    }
}
    

struct FoodView: View{
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            Text("food destination view ");
        }
    }
}

struct AddFoodView: View{
    @Binding var pushed : Bool
    @EnvironmentObject private var fridgeView : Fridge
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var count : Int = 1
    @State private var category : String = "肉类";
    @State var showCategory = false
    @State var showCount = false
    var someNumberProxy: Binding<String> {
            Binding<String>(
                get: { String(format: "%d", Int(self.count)) },
                set: {
                    if let value = NumberFormatter().number(from: $0) {
                        self.count = value.intValue;
                    }
                }
            )
        }

    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                
                    Button (action: {
                        self.pushed = false ;
                        //let tempFood=Food(id: fridgeView.index!,name: name, count: count, category: category);
                        //fridgeView.addFood(food: tempFood);
                    } ){
                        Text("save").foregroundColor(Color.blue).font(.system(size: 18,design: .default)) }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Three")
            }
                    
            
            ZStack{
                    if self.showCount{
                        Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
                            .opacity(0.5)
                        VStack(){
                            Spacer(minLength: 0);
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.showCount=false;
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Done")
                                }).frame(alignment: .trailing).offset(x:-15,y:15)
                            }
                            Picker(selection: $count,label: EmptyView()) {
                                ForEach(1..<100){ number in
                                    Text("\(number)").tag("\(number)")
                                }
                            }.labelsHidden()
                        }            .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: 300, minHeight: 250, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: 250, alignment: .top).fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 27).fill(Color.white.opacity(1)))
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 27).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                        .offset(x:10,y:-10)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    if self.showCategory{
                        let categoryArr = ["肉类","蔬菜类","饮料类","调味品类"]
                        ZStack{
                            Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
                                .opacity(0.5)
                            VStack(){
                                Spacer(minLength: 0);
                                HStack{
                                    Spacer()
                                    Button(action: {
                                        self.showCategory=false;
                                    }, label: {
                                        Text("Done")
                                    }).frame(alignment: .trailing).offset(x:-15,y:15)
                                }
                                Picker(selection: $category,label: EmptyView()) {
                                    ForEach(0..<categoryArr.count){ number in
                                        Text(categoryArr[number]).tag(categoryArr[number])
                                    }
                                }.labelsHidden()
                            }            .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: 300, minHeight: 250, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: 250, alignment: .top).fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 27).fill(Color.white.opacity(1)))
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 27).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                            Spacer()
                        }.offset(x:10,y:20)
                    }
            }
        }.animation(.easeInOut)
    }
        
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

If you read my code carefully, there are some variables are missing referencing. That's because I pasted part of the code that relates to my issue.

Food Class

```
//
//  Food.swift
//  refridgerator_app
//
//  Created by Mingtao Sun on 12/23/20.
//

import Foundation
class Food: Identifiable {
    init(id:Int, name: String, count: Int, category: String){
        self.id=id;
        self.name=name;
        self.count=count;
        self.category=category;
    }
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var count: Int
    var category: String
}
```

Fridge class

```
//
//  Fridge.swift
//  refridgerator_app
//
//  Created by Mingtao Sun on 12/27/20.
//

import Foundation
class Fridge: ObservableObject{
    init(){
        db=DBhelper();
        let result = setIndex(database: db!);
        self.index = result.1;
        self.container=result.0;
    }
    var db:DBhelper?
    var index : Int?
    @Published var container : [Food]?;
    
    func setIndex(database: DBhelper) -> ([Food],Int){
        let foodList : [Food] = database.read();
        var index=0;
        for food in foodList{
            index = max(food.id,index);
        }
        return (foodList,(index+1));
    }
    
    func updateindex(index: inout Int){
        index=index+1;
    }
    
    func testExist(){
        if let data = db {
            print("hi")
        }
        else{
            print("doesnt exist")
        }
    }
    
    func addFood(food:Food){
        self.db!.insert(id: self.index!, name: food.name, count:food.count, category: food.category);
        self.container!.append(food);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: "But then I don't know why my own code pasted below does work." Do I understand you correctly that you want an explanation on why your code works right?

Comment: Could you provide `Fridge` code to test?

Comment: @Simon Nah. My code doesn't work as expected. It should go back to root. But it didn't.

Comment: @Asperi I provided the code i have for Fridge and Food class. Basically, after pressing save, it should go back to root view (content view) but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because you implemented a new `NaviagtionView` in `AddFoodView`. Simply remove this and it should work. Look at the link you provided. There is no `NavigationView` in the child.

Correct me if Im wrong but the core code parts here that produce this issue are as follows:

Here you start:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var pushed: Bool = false
    // Deleted other vars
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationView {
                List(fridge.container!){
                    food in NavigationLink(destination: FoodView()) {
                        Text("HI")
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Fridge Items"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                        // Here you navigate to the child view
                                        NavigationLink(destination: AddFoodView(pushed: self.$pushed),isActive: self.$pushed) {
                                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle").resizable().frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                                        }.isDetailLink(false) )
            }
```

Here you land and want to go back to root:

```
struct AddFoodView: View{
    
    @Binding var pushed : Bool
    // Deleted the other vars for better view
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{  // <-- remove this
                VStack{
                
                    Button (action: {
                        // here you'd like to go back
                        self.pushed = false;
                    } ){
                        Text("save").foregroundColor(Color.blue).font(.system(size: 18,design: .default)) }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Three")
            }
```

For the future:

I have the feeling you might have troubles with the navigation in general.

Actually it is really simple:

You implement one `NavigationView` at the "root" / start of your navigation.
From there on you only use `NavigationLinks` to go further down to child pages. No `NavigationView` needed anymore.

Comment: Hmmm Thanks. I'm such a newbie maybe I didn't understand SwiftUI detailed enough. So navigationView is just like a view for the root right?

Comment: You will get the hang of it quite fast I'm sure! Here are some good tutorials. Long one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nA6Jo6YnL9g&feature=emb_title / Short one: https://daddycoding.com/2020/02/17/swiftui-navigationview/

Comment: I just tried your code without navigationView. It is not working as expected too. Basically I copied and paste your button action code to my `struct AddFoodView` and try to see if a simple button will take me back to the root page. It did not.

Comment: I just tested. The problem is that in my ContentView. If I use `navigationBarTrailing`  or `NavigationBarItem(trailing:navigation link )`, then I wasn't able to pop back, if I use simply a button then I am able to pop back. Do. you probably know how to fix the issue?

Comment: I found a thread who has the same issue as mine. I'm going to test the provided answer. I think its kind of a bug. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649430/navigationlink-isactive-does-not-work-inside-navigationbaritemstrailing-modif)

Comment: Actually it is really simple:

"You implement one NavigationView at the "root" / start of your navigation. From there on you only use NavigationLinks to go further down to child pages. No NavigationView needed anymore." - Spot on, I've struggled a lot with this until your answer - write a blog post :)